# History referencing in Pine Script arrays

Tags: arrays, pine-script

I have been trying to use array feature, which recently has been introduced in PineScript 4, but it seams that either I'm not aware of its limitations, or , possibly the implementation is still buggy.
The problem I'm faced with is illustrated by the following very simple script:

```
//@version=4

study("TEST")

// A is basically the same as bar_index+1, and it is plotted as expected
A=0
A:=nz(A[1])+1

// the same thing implemented using arrays nevertheless doesn't work as expected
B=array.new_float(1,0)
array.set(B,0,nz(array.get(B,0)[1])+1)

plot(A,color=color.red)
plot(array.get(B,0),color=color.yellow)
```

According to my understanding both **A** and the first element of **B** array must produce identical graphs.
Nevertheless plot of **B** simply gives 1 on all bars.
The problem is definitely related to the usage of history referencing operator [].
Does anybody know how to overcome this kind of issue?

*Note*: I've made this script as simple as possible in order to get to the guts of the problem. The script I'm working on is much more complex, and it uses arrays inside for-loops in various ways, including the one that has been just illustrated (i.e. history referencing op), so using simple variables in place of array simply doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Past instances of array id’s or elements cannot be referenced directly using Pine’s [ ] history-referencing operator (https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Arrays.html?highlight=array#history-referencing)
2. Fixed version of your example:

```
//@version=4

study("TEST")

// A is basically the same as bar_index+1, and it is plotted as expected
A=0
A:=nz(A[1])+1

// the same thing implemented using arrays nevertheless doesn't work as expected
var B=array.new_float(1,0)
array.set(B,0,nz(array.get(B,0))+1)

plot(A,color=color.red)
plot(array.get(B,0),color=color.yellow)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, Andrey, but the way you've fixed the script misses the whole point of history referencing problem in array elements. You are right, that past instances of array id’s or elements cannot be referenced directly using Pine’s [ ] history-referencing operator. And this is clearly explained by example in the docs: one can't write something like `array.get(a[1], 0)`. Nevertheless, using `array.get(a, 0)[1]` is perfectly fine (see the example in that same chapter you are referring to). Therefore I still think that history referencing implementation in arrays has issues.

Comment: Again , the purpose of my test script was not to find a way to make A and the 1st element of B plots identical by getting rid of history referencing operator all together, but to illustrate history referencing issue with respect to arrays, since I do need to access array elements history in my real scripts.

Comment: I think even though the expression `array.get (a, 0) [1]` compiles successfully, the operator `[1]` doesn't apply to anything at runtime.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't. And I think it is a bug. Otherwise why would they give this kind of construct in their own documentation in the first place. I'll keep running this code once in a while. I've already filed several array-related bugs similar to this one on tradingvidew site, and they eventually have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with you. I have problem with array historical refrencing too, which never solve by replacing of []. I rewrote my script without array and it's worked perfectly. Alas that was too long script but worked correctly. I think Pine staff should revise on arrays codes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).